# xlsxwriter: when setting column 0 width, width of all other columns gets reset

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I have created an `xls` workbook using `xlsxwriter`. I am trying to set the width of all the columns to a default value in the beginning, then adjusting the width of column 0 later in the script based on the cell content.
The problem is that when I do that the width of all the other columns gets reset.

Here is a minimal example representing the problem:

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('Num')

numArr = [0.000000520593523979187, 13.123456789, 1.789456, 0.002345, 0.00123]

for i,num in enumerate(numArr):
    ws.write_number(i, 0, num)

ws.set_row(0, 40)
ws.set_row(1, 50)
# Set column width to a default value
ws.set_column(0, 7, width = 20)
# Some other calculations
# Set column 0 width to a different value
ws.set_column(0, 0, 50)

wb.close()
```

This is the result:

[image]

The issue doesn't show when I set the width for example of column 1:

[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `set_column()` you need to set independent (non-overlapping) ranges.

So the following would work in your case:

```
ws.set_column(1, 7, width=20)
ws.set_column(0, 0, 50)
```